# Laravel Nova - Can`t see validation error messages

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I`m working on a project with Nova dashboard. For some reason I can`t see validation error messages.

If there is an validation error, I can see that as an exception in browser console. But not in Nova UI.

I can see success message, if all fields of form are input correctly.

I`m new to Nova, can anyone help me to debug this issue? I mean I don`t know where to look for to figure out this issue

**Error trace from browser**:

```
{
    "errors":"Sorry, something went wrong.",
    "exception":"Illuminate\\Validation\\ValidationException",
    "message":"The given data was invalid.",
    "trace":[{
        "file":"\/home\/ausvacs\/public_html\/nova\/src\/PerformsValidation.php",
        "line":18,
        "function":"validate",
        "class":"Illuminate\\Validation\\Validator",
        "type":"->",
        "args":[]
    }]
}
```

**Fields method of Agency nova model (Table name:agency)**:

```
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
        ID::make()->sortable(),

        Text::make('Name')
            ->sortable()
            ->rules('required', 'string'),

    ];
}
```

**Error on browser console**:

[image]

**Exception on browser network tab**:

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide the code & screenshots for more details

Comment: I have added error trace and fields method of my Nova model.

Comment: Your Nova resource code looks ok. Can you check the exception stack trace in laravel log file.

Comment: I checked. Its looks like there is no entry in laravel.log for this issue. I tried updating Nova, but that also did\`t make any difference.

Comment: Can you provide the input values your are submitting

Comment: I`m submitting null value. I mean I\`m just clicking submit without inputting anything. So it is expected to show an validation error message in Nove UI right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183683/discussion-between-vineeth-vijayan-and-saumini-navaratnam).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with in the Handler (app/Exceptions/Handler.php). Not sure if the previous developer updated this function. Anyway, the issues in this function are:

- Status code returning in the event of validation exception is 400, thats needs to 422. Then only Vue components will display validation messages.
- Also, in here the errors are pushed to "validation" index of "response" array. But Vue component is checking for "errors" index of "response" array.

```
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {    
        if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {

            $response = ['errors' => 'Sorry, something went wrong.'];

            $status = 400;

            if ($this->isHttpException($exception)) {
                $status = $exception->getStatusCode();
            }

            if (get_class($exception) == 'Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException') {
                $response['validation'] = $exception->validator->errors();
            }

            return response()->json($response, $status);
        }

        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```

The issue got fixed when I updated code to return error code as 422 in the event of validation exception and pushed errors into "errors" index of response instead of "validation" index.